# WindowManager, when I change the width of the window, t not changing immediately, but smooth

Tags: java, android, android-windowmanager

I add window:

```
FrameLayout scrimLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
scrimLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

scrimLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
  PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

scrimLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.END;
scrimLayoutParams.x = 0;
scrimLayoutParams.y = 0;
scrimLayoutParams.width = 0;
scrimLayoutParams.height = size.y;
wm.addView(scrimLayout, scrimLayoutParams);
```

And next I change width of this layout:

```
    scrimLayoutParams.width = 180;
    scrimLayoutParams.height = size.y;
    wm.updateViewLayout(scrimLayout, scrimLayoutParams);
```

And after `updateViewLayout` it not changing immediately, but smooth.

Comment: You can improve your question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the link "How to ask questions the smart way."

Comment: Maybe you added in your layout animation changes to true.
In my code it appears instantly, but with that flag its smooth.